# Can't access variable from .env file in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

When I try to console.log DOG, I got **Undefined** to console.
I installed `npm install dotenv`.

dotenv version: 16.3.1
node version: v18.16.0

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

console.log(process.env.DOG)
```

.env

```
DOG=16
```

My structure is:

- examples

  - index.js
- node_modules
- .env
- package.json
- package-lock.json

So, env file is not in the same folder as index.js, it is one folder outside.

I also tried in index.js:

```
require('dotenv').config(); 
const dog = process.env.DOG
console.log(dog)
```

but nothing. Although, nothing should change in this way.

It is like, index.js cannot read from .env or cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The default behavior is to look for `.env` in the process's working directory.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#path)

If your working directory is the directory where `.env` is and you run `node examples/index.js`, it should work.

If your working directory is `examples/` and you run `node index.js`, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you, it was a problem in the current working directory. Now it works.